NGINX How to allow Access From Angular App
I have 2 EC2 Instances one for my backend one for my Angular front end both uses nginx as reverse proxy below is my nginx config for my angular server
However when an api call is called on the angular app on the browser the request is blocked,
it seems like the browser ip address is what the backend nginx receives
i want to make sure only the request from my angular app is allowed on my backend how do i do this??
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
# Define a custom log format for the /api location
log_format api_log '\$remote_addr - \$remote_user [\$time_local] "
                   "\$request" \$status \$body_bytes_sent '
                   '"\$http_referer" "\$http_user_agent"';

# Define a custom log format for other locations
log_format main '\$remote_addr - \$remote_user [\$time_local] "
                "\$request" \$status \$body_bytes_sent '
                '"\$http_referer" "\$http_user_agent"';

# Access log for the whole server
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

server {
    listen 80;

    location /api/ {

        allow EC2_IP_ADDRESS;
        deny all;

        proxy_pass http://music-user-adapter:8080; # Forward requests to Spring Boot container
        proxy_set_header Host \$host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;

        # Use the custom log format for /api requests
        access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log api_log;
    }
  }
 }

i want to make sure only the request from my angular app is allowed on my backend how do i do this??
